# Gsuite Directory API Java: Get the last login time

Tags: java, google-workspace, google-directory-api

I want to get all the users that had never used the e-mail. I checked that those users have the LastLoginTime attribute like : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

Then I made a function to get all the users that has this time and inactivate them. The list of users code is like that:

```
 List<User> users = directory.users().list().setDomain(GSUITE_DOMAIN).setQuery("lastLoginTime='1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'").execute().getUsers();
```

but this code is given an error saying that the query is invalid.

I have tried with lastLoginTime:'1970' but same error.

any suggestion?